# .gitignore doesn't ignore files in directory .idea

Tags: git

I would like to let Git ignore all files, which are in the folder *.idea*.

I have added `.idea/` to the file *.gitignore* but when I call `git status`, it returns:

```
    deleted:    .idea/artifacts/zt_productions_war.xml
    modified:   .idea/compiler.xml
    deleted:    .idea/dataSources.xml
    deleted:    .idea/dataSources/6b173822-9142-4814-812e-260d887515a7.xml
    deleted:    .idea/libraries/Maven__javax_servlet_javax_servlet_api_4_0_1                                                                                                                                                                                               .xml
    deleted:    .idea/libraries/Maven__junit_junit_4_11.xml
    deleted:    .idea/libraries/Maven__org_hamcrest_hamcrest_core_1_3.xml
    deleted:    .idea/libraries/Maven__org_mariadb_jdbc_mariadb_java_client_                                                                                                                                                                                               2_4_1.xml
    modified:   .idea/misc.xml
    deleted:    .idea/modules.xml
    deleted:    lib/javax.annotation.jar
    deleted:    lib/javax.ejb.jar
    deleted:    lib/javax.jms.jar
    deleted:    lib/javax.persistence.jar
    deleted:    lib/javax.resource.jar
    deleted:    lib/javax.servlet.jar
    deleted:    lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jar
    deleted:    lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar
    deleted:    lib/javax.transaction.jar
    modified:   src/main/webapp/assets/css/style.css
    modified:   src/main/webapp/assets/css/style.css.map
    modified:   src/main/webapp/assets/css/style.sass
    modified:   src/main/webapp/backend/chat.html
```

Why are the files in the .idea directory getting listed?

Comment: Did you do `git add .gitignore` and commit it?

Comment: Because an earlier commit has added them to the repository, so they're already being tracked.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider yes, I did.